# Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String'
```

with the code below. I checked other posts with this error - they indicate that the dictional is an optional and must be unwrapped first - but in this case the dictionary is NOT wrapped - so I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
    if let jsonArticleItems = jsonResult["response"]!["docs"]! as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for jsonArticleItem in jsonArticleItems {
            var feedArticleItem = FeedArticleItem()
            feedArticleItem.identifier = jsonArticleItem["_id"] <-- ERROR HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

Turned out I needed to cast the value of the dictionary entry:

```
        feedArticleItem.identifier = jsonArticleItem["_id"]! as? String
```

The warning is NOT super useful